# jq - How to select objects where a field is 'false'?

Tags: boolean, jq

I'm having trouble implementing boolean checks into jq.
If I have a field "test" which can be a boolean true or false, how do I use select to find this?

Initially I tried the following:

```
jq '.[] | select(.test=="false")'
```

But I think I am comparing strings here so this will not work.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The JSON boolean values are `true` and `false`, so just drop the quotation marks, e.g. `select(.test == false)`.

If indeed the values of .test are known beforehand to be strictly boolean, then you could simplify your filter to just:

```
.[] | select(.test|not)
```

Comment: What about `not .test`? https://github.com/stedolan/jq/issues/2486 so it is pretty opaque: `select(.test | not)`

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution

```
map(select(.test))
```

Comment: This will work in that it is given that the values of .test are boolean, but of course the result will be an array.